# How to make Trajectory Predictor on my ball?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]hey guys , So as you can see i made a robot arm grab a slingshot's objectholder with a ball in it. My arm pulls it any direction I want it but I wanted the user to know which box is going to be shot at.

Answer (score 0):

If you're applying an impulse force (or velocity) to your ball and there is gravity in your world, your item will follow the **Projectile motion**;

Here you can find details about it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion

Comment: Would this be easier to make ? Because I’m looking at videos for it and i don’t see much . Maybe u can help if a projectile motion is good for it . So my thing is My ball is on kinematic when it starts and its pulled back and when my claw opens , the ball shoots because the holder that is holding the ball has spring joints . So that’s why I’m able to make the ball shoot . But i really don’t know which one would be easier and better to make for it to go a direction the user wants to with a trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two main options

#### [calculating it yourself](https://schatzeder.medium.com/basic-trajectory-prediction-in-unity-8537b52e1b34)

This is probably way better for performance especially if you want a really simple trajectory preview without accounting for any collision etc

refer to linked article. But it basically comes down to

[image]

and would need slightly rework from 2D to 3D physics, should be trivial though since the important part about the Y axis basically stays the same.

You would

1. Call this simulation with according supposed shoot direction and velocity
2. Visualize the tracked positions e.g. in a `LineRenderer`

#### [`Physics.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html)

This allows you to run physics updates manually all within a single frame and actually let the Physics engine handle it all for you

This costs of course a lot of performance but you get all collisions etc accounted for automatically without getting a headache

You would

1. Make a snapshot of all Rigid bodies in your scene - in order to reset after the simulation
2. Simulate the desired amount of physics steps (XY seconds ahead) while keeping track of the simulated data
3. reset everything to the state tracked in step 1
4. use the simulated data from step 2 to visualize e.g. with a `LineRenderer`

This **might** look somewhat like e.g.

```cs
public class Prediction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer line;
    public Rigidbody tracked;

    private Rigidbody[] allRigidbodies;

    private void Awake()
    {
        allRigidbodies = FindObjectsOfType<Rigidbody>();
    }
   
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Wherever you would get this from
        Vector3 wouldApplyForce;

        
        // Step 1 - snapshot
        // For simplicity reasons for now just the positions
        // using some Linq magic
        var originalPositions = allRigidbodies.ToDictionary(item => item, item => item.position);
        
        // Step 2 - Simulate e.g. 2 seconds ahead
        var trackedPositions = new Vector3 [(int) (2 / Time.fixedDeltaTime)];
        Physics.autoSimulation = false;
        tracked.AddForce(wouldApplyForce);
        for(var i = 0; i < trackedPositions.Length; i++)
        {
            Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            trackedPositions[i] = tracked.position;
        }

        // Step 3 - reset
        foreach (var kvp in originalPositions)
        {
            kvp.Key.position = kvp.Value;
        }

        Physics.autoSimulate = true;

        // Step 4 - Visualize
        line.positionCount = trackedPositions.Length;
        line.SetPositions(trackedPositions);
    }
}
```

Of course we won't talk about performance here ^^

Comment: This is very interesting… which one do u think would be better ? 
My ball is on kinematic when it starts and  its pulled back and when my claw opens , the ball shoots because the holder that is holding the ball has spring joints . So that’s why I’m able to make the ball shoot . But i really don’t know which one would be easier and better to make for it to go a direction the user wants to with a trajectory.