# Ball flick movement along a drawn path in Unity 3D space is not far enough

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

I'm creating a 3D soccer game in Unity, where the player can draw a path on the screen, and a soccer ball is supposed to follow this path in a 3D space. The path is supposed to consider the depth, height, and X axis. The player should be able to draw the path in a limited space, that's why I'm using an invisible box collider where the player can draw.
But right now I'm not getting the desired behavior that is the user should be able to draw the path taking the depth into account, so the ball can follow the path towards the goal, right now the player can draw on the screen but it's only taking the x and y values into account.

I'm using a LineRenderer to draw the path and then moving the ball along the path using a Coroutine. I've implemented a system where the user draws a path and then, on release of the mouse button or touch, the ball is set to the starting position of the path and moved along the path using Vector3.Lerp.
[image: this is what I'm getting]

```
private void Update()
    {
        // Left mouse button or touch.
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            // Raycast to the drawArea to draw the path.
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider == drawArea)
            {
                if (points.Count == 0 || (points.Count > 0 && Vector3.Distance(points[points.Count - 1], hit.point) > 0.1f))
                {
                    points.Add(hit.point);
                    lineRenderer.positionCount = points.Count;
                    lineRenderer.SetPositions(points.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            ball.position = points[0];
            StartCoroutine(MoveBallAlongPath());
            points.Clear();
            lineRenderer.positionCount = 0;
        }
    }
private IEnumerator MoveBallAlongPath()
{
    // The resolution of the path.
    int resolution = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        Vector3 pointA = points[i];
        Vector3 pointB = points[i + 1];
        Vector3 controlPoint = (pointA + pointB) / 2;
            
        for (int j = 0; j < resolution; j++)
        {
            float t = j / (float)resolution;
            Vector3 pointOnLine = CalculateBezierPoint(t, pointA, controlPoint, pointB);
            ball.position = pointOnLine;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
}

private Vector3 CalculateBezierPoint(float t, Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
{
    float u = 1 - t;
    float tt = t * t;
    float uu = u * u;

    Vector3 p = uu * p0;
    p += 2 * u * t * p1;
    p += tt * p2;

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Its not clear how you want to handle the 3rd dimension.  Do you want it to always extend into the goal?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: You could take the distance from the ball to goal, divide it by the number of points in your path to get the step distance, then add to each point `forward * index * step`.

Comment: what is points and where is it assigned?

Comment: @AND4011002849 is the box collider aligned perpendicular to camera.forward?

Comment: @Obscure021 yes. it is

Comment: You could create drag handles on your path that can be modified from different orientations.  Basically have drag handles along the path.  Then from top you could drag the end handle to the goal, and from the side drag the middle handle up or down, or wherever.  Unfortunately its not clear how you expect to draw in 2d but have it extend into the 3rd dimension.

Comment: Another potential option is to use time as your depth.  So as you draw the points, they extend further out as time goes on.

Comment: Since the box collider is perpendicular, the 3rd dimension is not included. You will need to include the colliders of the ground. net etc, instead. Then add invisible colliders on the sides to avoid NullRefrenceException. See, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jTPKz3ga4w, in this video the tutor also takes into account the third dimension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73891691/how-to-make-trajectory-predictor-on-my-ball

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a simpler solution idea for this if that helps. Put the invisible box collider covering the entire goal post frontside only. There will be two touch/click actions. The first click/touch will set the ball position on the ground. Like a ray cast on the field/ground to snap the ball with the ground and move it with mouse/touch to set the position of the ball, then release the click/touch when you are done. Next click/touch should be on the goal post only to ray cast on the invisible box collider to set where to aim the shot. after releasing, you can either shoot the ball straight to the goal post connecting the two points or can add a third and fourth click action that will probably set the connecting line's concavity/curvature. You can show two gizmos, one will decide the concavity and another will decide the rotation of the curve like a 3D modeling software may have. But you can just keep it simple if you just shoot the ball straight to the goal post.